# Why the "Filesystem root" has only XXX disk space remaining?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, disk-usage

The title is pretty obvious and common: the error below happens very often.
[image: Error message]

What I am asking is why does it happen. I mean, look at the output of `GParted` (the first 4 partition are required by `Windows`)
[image: GParted output]

It seems very obvious that I have a lot of free space on all the partitions. So, why the system says that the remaining space is so low?

Comment: Are you sure about that? From the looks of it, you only have a couple of gigabytes free in the partitions you use for Ubuntu. How is that a lot of free space? Also, why is /dev/sda4 empty?

Comment: In this case, I think it's the difference between *unused* and *available* space (i.e. the filesystem's reserved blocks): see this similar Q&A [Why are the free space and available space not the same in system monitor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/670954/why-used-available-space-is-less-than-total-space?lq=1)

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste sure it is not very much, but it seems that Ubuntu partition has >>3GiB, while sometimes the system says that I have 0 MiB left. `/dev/sd4/` is a `Windows 8` partition btw, and even though it seems empty, it has a lot of space used.

Comment: @steeldriver it seems the most plausible solution until now and I think this is the problem. If `ext4` works in the same way of `ext3`, it reserves 5% of space to root; in my case it is ~2.5GiB that I can't use. If you can, please provide this as an answer and it will be the accepted one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space that is showing as "unused" is not necessarily available to the user.

Specifically, filesystems from the `ext` family reserve a number of disk blocks for system tasks as described here:

- [ext2/3/4 reserved blocks percentage purpose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/ext2-3-4-reserved-blocks-percentage-purpose)
- [Reserved space for
  root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

The default amount of reserved space for these filesystems is 5%.

From your screenshots we can see that your root filesystem is located on a partition of size 48.83GiB, so we would expect 48.83 x .05 = 2.44GiB reserved. The unused space is shown as 3.13GiB so that the *available* space should then be 3.13 - 2.44 = 0.69GiB - close to the 722.6MB shown by the warning message. (There will be rounding errors since the usage is only given to 2 decimals; also one is **Gi**B and one is **M**B).

You can confirm the reserved block fraction using the `dumpe2fs` utility. For example, using my own boot partition:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | less
```

I can see that

```
Block count:              248832
Reserved block count:     12441
```

from which the reserved percentage is 12441/248832 x 100 = 5.00% as expected.

The reserved block fraction can be modified using the `tune2fs` utility, however I would not recommend doing that in this case - it's more appropriate for large (>TB) and/or non-system disks.

Answer (score 0):

Temp files can take several gigabytes, so a few free gigabytes is not much.

Try cleaning your computer with [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) (runs on Wine perfectly well). That will give you a graphical overview of where your disk space is going.

Also, you could use WinDirStat when you get a warning to check if the free space you think there is, isn't taken by some temporary file.

There are alternatives to WinDirStat that run native on Linux like KDirStat, but I always found WinDirStat to be better.

Good luck.

Comment: ubuntu has a `Disk Usage Analyzer` built-in.

Comment: It is a good tool, but it doesn't answer my question:

Comment: I can't consider this an answer. Besides it being wrong (it will  not be due to temp files but due to reserved blocks) Windows tools are off topic, even more so when we have our own tools for this.

Comment: There is also KDirStat, but I find WinDirStat to be much better (and it does not require KDE libs). For this question this will indeed not be the correct answer. I hope however that it still can be useful for people coming across this question.

Comment: Cleaning temp files is circumventing the question actually :) Which was not what I meant to do, but it is what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Do an apt-get clean to remove old package files and apt-get autoremove to remove unnecesary dependencies. Do du -hs /var/log to see if you have vry large logfiles.