# Trying to free up some space: Where is my space going?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        31G   28G  1.4G  96% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            5.8G  4.0K  5.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.7M  1.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  113M  5.8G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
```

- Size: 31G
- User: 28G
- Avail: 1.4G

If my math serves me correct, it's that slightly incorrect? I'm trying to free up some space!

You can ignore `/opt` and `/home`, they sit on their own partitions.

```
karl@karl-laptop:/$ sudo du -sh *
9.8M    bin
450M    boot
4.0K    cdrom
241M    data
4.0K    dev
81M etc
50G home
0   initrd.img
0   initrd.img.old
2.3G    lib
3.5M    lib32
4.0K    lib64
16K lost+found
12K media
4.0K    mnt
15G opt
du: cannot access ‘proc/9592/task/9592/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/9592/task/9592/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/9592/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/9592/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   proc
364M    root
du: cannot access ‘run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
3.6M    run
15M sbin
16G srv
0   sys
26M tmp
7.2G    usr
1.3G    var
0   vmlinuz
0   vmlinuz.old
```

Comment: Do `cd /;du -sh *`

Comment: What math are you doing, exactly? Did you take into account [filesystem reserved blocks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/684700/why-the-filesystem-root-has-only-xxx-disk-space-remaining/685400#685400)?

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus Done!

Comment: @steeldriver Will read!

Answer (score 2):

> By default, 5% of the filesystem blocks will be reserved for the
>   super-user, to avoid fragmentation and "allow root-owned daemons to
>   continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are
>   prevented from writing to the filesystem" (from man mkfs.ext4).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ext4#Reserved_blocks

With that in mind, it adds up to 31GB (some rounding is taking place):

```
>>> 0.05 * 31
1.55
>>> 28 + 1.4 + 1.55
30.95
```

You can tune that value to be less than 5% (follow the aforementioned link), though that is not recommended in this case. To free up space consider `apt-get clean` (see the man page for details). Also, consider installing the software `ncdu`, which is like a `du` file browser in ncurses, where you can navigate through the filesystem and folders/files are ordered by the size they take up. Check out what libraries/binaries/docs are taking up the most space and uninstall them via `apt-get purge <package>`. First make sure you don't need them, of course: `apt-cache rdepends --installed <package>`. The later lists what packages depend on the one you intend to uinstall. Do not uninstall if you see something in there (unless there is some "circular" dependencies, i.e. call `apt-cache ...` again on the results if you think that might be the case).

You can also look for uninstalled packages of which config files etc were kept back: `dpkg -l | grep ^rc`. You can automatically purge them using some `cut` shenanigans: `dpkg -l | grep ^rc | cut -d" " -f3 | perl -p -e 's/\n/ /g'`

You can also safely remove old logs if that's taking up too much space.