# df reports several gb delta between total and used, but 0 available space

Tags: files, disk-usage, user-space

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdb        246G  234G     0 100% /backup_data

on the above fs:
as root i can create non-empty files in the above tree, /backup_data.
as the owner of a dir in the above tree, with perms 775 on the dir which i
am attempting to write  to,
i can create only empty files. any attempt to write data to a new or existing
file, fails.
it seems as if root has the capability to utilize space which regular users (even with appropriate perms) cannot utilize.

any explanation for this?

tnx
ams

Comment: Yes - a percentage of the filesystem is reserved for root only. See for example [Why the “Filesystem root” has only XXX disk space remaining?](https://askubuntu.com/a/685400/178692)

Comment: You also have to give yourself ownership & permissions to use the partition. If an internal drive, you want to mount with fstab. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942 but use your mount point. And: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting